# why does the following code executing the lambda function instead of the f(x) above?

Tags: python, function

Title

I don't understand why the following code ignores the first function and run the second instead.

```
def f(x):
    return 100
f = lambda x: 1 if x < 2 else x + f(x-1)
print(f(5))
```

the output is 15.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you expect it to run the first function?

Comment: `def f(x)...` is equivalent to `f = lambda x: 100` in this case (with more complex function this doesn't hold true.

Comment: Function definitions don't somehow trump assignments - `f` is just like any other variable. You've first assigned `f` to a function that returns `100`. Then, you assign `f` to another function. Then, you call `f` - obviously, `f` now is the lambda function you defined, so it will call that.

Answer (score 2):

You define the first function as **f**.  You immediately over-write that with a *different* function, calling *that* one **f**.  This is just as if you'd run the code:

```
f = [1, 2, 3]
f = 7
print f
```

You will get only the **7**; the list is lost.

Answer (score 1):

The second definition of `f` overrides the first.  Variables can't have two values.  And function names are effectively just variables.  When you assign to `f`, you overwrite the value of `f`, so the original function is no longer accessible.